# Swipe through text, iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swipe

I want to `swipe` through several pages of text over an `static` background image.
First I wanted to do it with a `PageViewController` but there the `background swipes` with the text, what is not what I want.

Does someone know how to do this?

Thank you and
Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert your PageViewController in a view inside the viewController.
So that you can keep background from viewController and use your PageView without background on it.

Comment: how can you do that? I can not insert a PageViewController into a view (using storyboarding)

Further more in the Apple documentation you can read:"each page is managed by its own view controller object" https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/index.html

So I am not sure if this can work.

Comment: @LilK3ks By adding your PageView as child of your viewcontroller. Like you can do with tableviews or collectionviews... Something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17597051/uipageviewcontroller-inside-a-custom-uiviewcontroller I don't really use storyboard, but i think there is a solution also using it.

Comment: Ahhh - now it works :D 
... I'm using a collection to display the pages - so I had to change the background of the collections view controller - things make sense now =)
Thanks a lot!